# Split then with ifs

Tags: node.js

I have this function:

```
function insert(foo, bar) {
  return find(foo)
    .then(i => create(i, bar.name, true))
    .then(i => delete(i))
    .then(i => i);
}
```

what I would like is to add an if like this (I ALREADY KNOW THIS IS NOT POSSIBLE BUT I NEED TO FIND THE BEST WAY TO DO IT)

```
function insert(foo, bar) {
  return find(foo)
    if(bar.name === 'x'){
       .then(i => create(i, bar.name, true))
       .then(i => delete(i))
       .then(i => i);
    }else return foo;
}
```

One way to do it would be like

```
function insert(foo, bar) {
  return find(foo)
    .then(i => {
         if(bar.name === 'x')return f(foo,bar)
         else return i
     }
}

function f(i, bar.name){
     create(i, bar.name, true))
        .then(i => delete(i))
        .then(i => i);
    }
```

Is there any other optimal way to do it?
TY!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give your callback to find a body:

```
function insert(foo, bar) {
  return find(foo)
    .then(i => {
      if (bar.name !== "x") return foo;

      return create(i, bar.name, true)
        .then(created => delete(created));
    });
}
```

or, use [`async/await`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) to make it look more synchronous:

```
async function insert(foo, bar) {
  const found = await find(foo);

  if (!found.name) return foo;

  const created = await create(found, bar.name, true);
  const deleted = await delete(i);

  return deleted;
}
```

Also, I would advise against a function called `delete` since it could easily be confused with the [`delete`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete) keyword.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you just need to move your if clause to find(foo) only if bar.name == 'x'

```
    function insert(foo, bar) {
    if(bar.name === 'x'){
        return find(foo)
            .then(i => create(i, bar.name, true))
            .then(i => delete(i))
            .then(i => i);
    } else return foo
}
```

Alternatively, if you need to call find(foo) either way, you just need to add in another .then containing a function with the if statement

```
function insert(foo, bar) {
return find(foo)
.then((i) => {
    if(bar.name === 'x'){
        return create(i, bar.name, true)
            .then(i => delete(i))
            .then(i => i);
    } else return foo
})
```

}

Comment: This is actually what I don't need to do, and also I did what you say in the second piece of code. So, thank you!

Comment: I just now realized that that first part was in the what I don't need to do section. Whoops! Clearly I need to read better. Glad, I was still able to help though :)